# How to change GUI button highlighted color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change GUI button highlighted color when I press the button. However, I do not find how can I change in my Script onGUI() method.

I did not show the whole code. The necessary part is below.

Here is onGUI() method;

if-else checks the button is clicked or not.

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(currentPart.DrawDepth * spacing + x + subPartsSpacing, y, 200, 20), currentPart.EnglishTitle,myStyle))
{
    if (!currentPart.IsClicked)
    {
        currentPart.IsClicked = true;
        HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode showModeFullBody = HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.Invisible;
        bodyVisualizer.ShowBody(showModeFullBody);

        AllSubPartsAndRoot.Insert(AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count, currentPart);
        addAllSubPartsOfClickButton(currentPart, AllSubPartsAndRoot, AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count - 1);
        HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode showModeCurrentPart = HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent;

        for (int i = 0; i < AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count; i++)
        {
            bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(showModeCurrentPart, AllSubPartsAndRoot[i]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        currentPart.IsClicked = false;
        List<HumanBodyPart> RemoveBodyParts = new List<HumanBodyPart>();
        RemoveBodyParts.Insert(0,currentPart);
        addAllSubPartsOfClickButton(currentPart, RemoveBodyParts, 1);

        for(int i = 0; i < RemoveBodyParts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (AllSubPartsAndRoot.Contains(RemoveBodyParts[i]))
            {      
                bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.Invisible, RemoveBodyParts[i]);
                AllSubPartsAndRoot.Remove(RemoveBodyParts[i]);
            }
        }

        if(AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count == 0)
        {
            bodyVisualizer.ShowBody(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent);
        }
        else
        {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < AllSubPartsAndRoot.Count; ii++)
            {
                bodyVisualizer.ShowBodyPart(HumanBodyVisualizer.ShowMode.LowTransparent, AllSubPartsAndRoot[ii]);
            }    
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: and where is your `myStyle` ?

Comment: ` private GUIStyle myStyle = new GUIStyle();`              
        `myStyle.normal.textColor = Color.white;`
        `myStyle.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;`
        `myStyle.fontSize = 14;`
        `myStyle.fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a custom `GUIStyle`.

You can change the `pressed` style via the [`onActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-onActive.html)

> Rendering settings for when the element is turned on and pressed down.

and the [`active`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-active.html)

> Rendering settings for when the control is pressed down.

components of the `GUIStyle`

**But** you would need a `Texture2D` for it in

```
myStyle.onActive.background = SomeTexture2D;
```

unfortunately there is no way to directly change the color tint of a GUIStyle.

---

Note: In order to configure your GUIStyle more easely you can simply create an asset in the ProjectView → <kbd>right click</kbd> → `Create` → `GUISkin`

Do all your settings here via the Inspector and simply reference this `GUISkin` asset in your EditorScript and use `GUI.skin = myReferencedGuiSkin;`

---

Alternatively you can try and use the button to turn on a flag.

You could maybe use [`Event.current`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html) and check if it's [`type`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-type.html) is `EventType.MouseUp` or the [`mousePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-mousePosition.html) is outside of the `rect` you use for the button in order to reset the flag. (Not sure if this will work though)

```
private bool pressed;
private bool hovered;

...

public void OnGUI()
{
    var color = GUI.color;
    var rect = new Rect(...);
    var ev = Event.current;

    hovered = ev.mousePosition.x > rect.x && ev.mousePosition.x < rect.x + rect.width && ev.mousePosition.y > rect.y && ev.mousePosition.y < rect.y + rect.height;

    if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp) pressed = false;
    else if (ev.type == EventType.MouseDown) pressed = true;

    if (hovered && pressed) GUI.color = Color.green;
    if (GUI.Button(rect, ...))
    {
        ...
    }
    GUI.color = color;

    // in order to receive the mouse events
    Repaint();
}
```

If this is an EditorWindow you have to make sure [`wantsMouseMove`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow-wantsMouseMove.html) is set to `true` in order to receive mouse events.

[image]